# Authentication Error(Netlify Login Issue)

Tags: netlify, netlify-cms, netlify-function, netlify-cli, netlify-form

Authentication Error
Authenticating failed due to the following error: Your account requires additional verification. Please check your email and follow the instructions to verify your account.
I did not recevie any email form Netlify team!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPYww.png)
2Days after!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5CHX.png)

Actually First time I try to Signin Netlify Account with My Github! then i had recevie One mail form netlify and** Suddenly my Pc was ShutDown** After I had try to login the Netlify account they Throws Some Error like **"Authentication Error" and "We were unable to verify your identity and reinstate your Netlify account."**

Comment: This is nothing anyone on stackoverflow can help with.  I suggest you contact Netlify's support team (https://www.netlify.com/support) as they will have to help you untangle things.  Nothing Netlify did caused your PC to shut down though, perhaps you have some other unrelated problems with your PC.